# How to search Startswith and Endswith in Elasticsearch using Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring-Data-Elasticsearch and I have the following queries,

```
findByStatusIdAndLinkStartingWith(String statusId, String link);
findByStatusIdAndLinkEndingWith(String statusId, String link);
```

And it works fine. But I need to know how to implement this in `CriteriaQuery` or with `NativeSearchQueryBuilder`? And also I have seen that `StartingWith` is possible with `Prefix Query` but says it will slow. So what is underlying query used in `findByStatusIdAndLinkStartingWith` by spring-data-elasticsearch? What is the correct and best way to implement the above in single query like `CriteriaQuery` or with `NativeSearchQueryBuilder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data Elasticsearch internally builds a `CriteriaQuery` for a repository method that has *StartingWith* in in it's name:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repository/query/parser/ElasticsearchQueryCreator.java#L113-L116:

```java
case STARTING_WITH:
  return criteria.startsWith(parameters.next().toString());
case ENDING_WITH:
  return criteria.endsWith(parameters.next().toString());
```

This `CriteriaQuery` is then processed to an Elasticsearch `QueryBuilder` (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/CriteriaQueryProcessor.java#L205-L210):

```java
case STARTS_WITH:
    query = queryStringQuery(searchText + '*').field(fieldName).analyzeWildcard(true);
    break;
case ENDS_WITH:
    query = queryStringQuery('*' + searchText).field(fieldName).analyzeWildcard(true);
    break;
```

which then will be given to the `RestHighLevelClient`.

So if you use a `CriteriaQuery` this will end in the same query being sent to Elasticsearch. If you have a different performant query, then you'll need to use a `NativeSearchQuery` to create that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.